# Wizards in Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, wizard

I need to create a wizard in MVC 4 and most of the part I have done, now what is bothering me is that my project requires that the values which I have inserted in the first step of the wizard should display like label in the next step. How to achieve that, can anyone help me with this?? It would be great if I'll get a fast response.

Thank you in advance!!

This is how I am writing the front end code of the application

```
<div class="wizard-step">
  <h3>Step 3: Check Eligibility</h3>
  <div class="editor-label" style="width: 25%">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-label" style="width: 25%">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MeterId)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeterId)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-label" style="width: 25%">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Program)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Program)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-label" style="width: 25%">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PeakLoad)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field MB12">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PeakLoad)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-label" style="width: 25%">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WifiBroadband)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field MB12">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.WifiBroadband)
  </div>
</div>
```

And the controller code is also there

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EnrollUser()
{
  EnrollmentEntity model = new EnrollmentEntity();
  BindAggregatorList(model);
  BindCBLMethod(model);
  BindDeviceManuList(model);
  BindDeviceModelList(model);
  BindDeviceTypeList(model);
  BindProgramList(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnrollUser(EnrollmentEntity model)
{
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: How are you saving the data between steps?

Comment: Show some code so we can understand what you are doing

Comment: I have used a single view and a single controller so the data is saved between the actions in model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have uploaded the code also. Now give a look on that and help me to resolve my issue. I also want to put all the validations.

Comment: The code you have posted does not really explain what you are doing. Is each step of your wizard a different view? How are your persisting the model between each step. How are you redirecting to the next step in the wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you guys for showing your interest in my problem and trying to resolve it. It is the other thing that any of the answer didn't helped me out or might be the question was not explained properly. But now I got the answer and I am posting it so that it may help to other.

My problem was that I had to show the values that I have inserted in the first screen as Non editable in the second screen and for that I have just used the `@Model.Username` at the place I wanted to display it. And yes for the server side validation like the I have posted back the data after each screen and returned the same model.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to keep things atomic, you can save the data from each step in a session object and then save everything together once the user has completed the wizard. You could also `POST` the data from the current and previous steps to the next step of the wizard.

Another option would be to save the partial to your database following each step of the wizard.

**Update**
Given the new constraints, and assuming you support only modern browsers (IE8+ and just about all versions of Firefox and Chrome that are in use), you could store the data using local storage. See [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't save the data in the Temp Data or in Session, as the form is very large and it is having a lots of data fields so my PM wants me to do this without using any of these options. And that is why I am just posting the form after the last step.

Comment: Updated the answer with a third option

Comment: Thank you for you answer but still, this answer is also not able to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you not save locally to a JSON file and post back using AJAX at the end?